# MonoGame 3.4 Windows Phone 8.1 - Viewport rendering under virtual hw buttons

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, screen-resolution, monogame

I'm developing a game for Windows and Windows Phone 8.1. The game runs in 800x480, which is set in the game class constructor:

```
graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 480;
graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
```

Works like a charm on PC, hovewer, when I run the game on a Nokia 630 with virtual buttons and actual resolution of 854x480, the viewport is rendered stretched under the virtual buttons.

If I try to get the actual resolution from the `spriteBatch` or the `graphics` or directly the `GraphicsDevice` class, I always get 800x480, while it's obvious that the real resolution is bigger (while on PC I am able to find out the the display is in 1920x1080).

Just to clarify, I currently have a very simple Draw method, with no other resolution or viewport changes whatsoever:

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(oc.colBack);
spriteBatch.Begin();
foreach (Mob mobUnit in oc.mob) {
    spriteBatch.Draw(sprSquare, mobUnit.position, origin: mobUnit.size / 2, color: oc.colMob * 0.8f);
}
spriteBatch.End();
base.Draw(gameTime);
```

Any ideas how to solve this?
Thanks.

PS: The status bar is NOT showing nor "pushing" the viewport to the side.

Comment: It could be related to this bug I reported recently https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/4018

Comment: "The behavior of the bug makes it very difficult to achieve Letterboxing / pillarboxing resolution independence so as far as I can tell the DX version is definitely broken." oh.. Yeah I'm using the DX version, I also tried your Monogame.Extended library - with no useful effect. So I guess that I'll have to wait for a patch or something. Unless somebody comes with a workaround - like scaling the viewport right up to the buttons, for which I need to know whether they're there and their size (which isn't 54px, since it's inside the stretched 800px...). Thanks :)

Comment: Yes that's right, I couldn't actually find a way to implement the DX version. Although, the real issue is that it shouldn't matter, monogame is intended to behave the same on all platforms. I'm sure they'll fix it in the next version, maybe there's some kind of workaround in your case though. Hopefully

Comment: @craftworkgames - since I cannot comment there because potato: do you have any idea how to solve this - [link](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/93224/back-button-press-on-windows-phone-8-1-monogame)? I have the same problem and no option I found works. No overrides, no HardwareButtons class, no nothing.. I'd consider this elementary. :\ Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that one.

Answer (score 0):

After some intensive research and computations, I've come up with a rather fishy workaround. In `Initialize` method:

```
 matScale = Matrix.CreateScale(1f, 1f, 1f);

 if (Window.ClientBounds.Width < Window.ClientBounds.Height) {
      var dpiY = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawDpiY;
      var dpiX = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawDpiX;
      if (dpiY < dpiX - 1) {
           matScale = Matrix.CreateScale(.937f,1f,1f);
      }
 }
```

`DpiX - 1` is because I actually got a 1px difference between the DPIs on PC - although PCs shouldn't clear the first if statement. The `.937f` is the percentage of 800px minus the size of the virtual buttons, which is around 50px. (It's 54px when the screen size is 854px, so that makes roughly 6.323% of the screen.)

And of course, in `Draw`:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(transformMatrix: matScale);
```

This works. I'll leave this question open though, because I believe this is not the right way to do it. If only all the documented methods of `ApplicationView` actually *were* there...